# Drag + hotkey to move windows to other viewports/workspaces with Compiz

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys, compiz, workspace, aero-snap

I normally have Compiz disabled on my Ubuntu box.  However, I decided to enable it so that I could get Windows 7's "[Aero Snap](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snap)" functionality.  (Instructions on how to get Aero Snap with Compiz are [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/get-aero-snap-in-ubuntu/), for anyone interested.)

I have Ctrl+1 through Ctrl+4 hotkeyed to switch to different workspaces, or viewports as Compiz calls them.  With Compiz disabled I was able to move a window to a different workspace by grabbing it (clicking and holding on its title bar) and then pressing the appropriate hotkey.  Since enabling Compiz, I can no longer do so.

Is there any way to get that functionality back?  I much prefer it to having to right click the window's title bar and choose from the "Move to Another Workspace" menu.

Comment: If you're using the cube, have you played around with Rotate Cube > Bindings > Rotate to Cube Face with Window?

Comment: I do not use the cube, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't discovered how to drag windows across workspaces with Compiz enabled yet, but I did discover something even better.  Using the "Put" section in CompizConfig Settings Manager, you can bind keys to move the active window to a specific or adjacent workspace.  Using the hotkeys alone is faster than having to drag while using the hotkeys, so it's a pretty good solution.

I'll leave this question open for a few days in case anyone has an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this. Change a setting(Edge Flip Move) in compiz-config-settings-manager. Then you can switch workspace while dragging your window.

[image]